# Adding values through Keypress function in jquery

Tags: jquery

if I focus on a textarea and I press ctrl + b it should add -b- -.b-

Through jquery! How is it achievable?

this is what I tried

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#textarea").on('focus',function(){
    var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
    if(code == 17 && code == 33) {
      $(this).val() + "-b- -.b-";
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to add the string "-b- -.b-" when you press <kbd>CTRL+b</kbd> you need:

- test if event.which is b in lowercase
- test if <kbd>CTRL</kbd> key pressed
- compute the current cursor position to insert the string there
- prevent the default action

The snippet:

```js
$("#textarea").on('keydown',function(e){
  if (e.ctrlKey && String.fromCharCode(e.which).toLocaleLowerCase() == 'b') {
    e.preventDefault();
    var cursorPosition = $(this).prop("selectionStart");
    this.value = this.value.substr(0, cursorPosition) + '-b- -.b-' + this.value.substr(cursorPosition);
    $(this).prop("selectionStart", cursorPosition + 3);
    $(this).prop("selectionEnd", cursorPosition + 3);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<textarea id="textarea"></textarea>
```

Comment: That is one great function you made. Can you add this that cursor should be placed between -b- -.b- when they appear

Comment: @Bruce Could you check and let me know?

Answer (score 0):

Use the keypress event and use the keycode/ctrlKey properties of the event data.

[jQuery Keypress](https://api.jquery.com/keypress/)

```js
$(function(){
  $("textarea").keypress(function(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 2 && e.ctrlKey) {
      $(this).val($(this).val() + "-b- -.b-");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea></textarea>
```